# Advice about scraping a JavaScript-heavy website

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I want to make a database with runners' information from the New York Marathon 2016 (http://results.nyrr.org/event/M2016/finishers). This is a javascript-heavy site that requires to click on each "Expand results" for every runner to load their information. As you can see, there are more than 50,000 runners, so this task is not easy.

I have been trying to use Python-selenium to do this. First, I clicked on "Show more" until I get the list of all runners. Then, I clicked on each runners' "Expand Results" button, and finally use BeautifulSoup to get the information I want. The problem of this method is that it is very slow and gives errors because sometimes there is no button to click.

I want to ask which methods exist to do this. Is there a better method to make this database? Any advice about better methods or how to improve mine will be appreciated.

Comment: Go into the network panel in your browser, find out what request gets sent when you expand a result, replicate it. No Selenium involved.

Comment: it seems ** http://results.nyrr.org/api/runners/finishers (POST) **  is using ** "pageSize":51 (in payload) ** if you want to just verify number of results you can change this number

Comment: @Ryan I am able to do the request.post that is sent when I expand the result. However, after using BeautifulSoup on the response, it seems that the data is not there, I cannot find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the code below. You can also use threading to improve the performance.

```
import json

import requests

API_URL = 'http://results.nyrr.org/api/runners/finishers'
PAGE_SIZE = 51


def get_page(index):
    request = requests.post(API_URL, {
        'ageGroup': None,
        'city': None,
        'eventCode': "M2016",
        'gender': None,
        'handicap': None,
        'pageIndex': index,
        'pageSize': PAGE_SIZE,
        'runnerId': None,
        'searchString': None,
        'sortColumn': "overallTime",
        'sortDescending': False
    })
    data = json.loads(request.text).get('response', {})
    items = data.get('items', [])
    store(items)
    return len(items) > 0


def store(items):
    """Store items into database"""
    # Write your code to store the given items
    print(items)


page = 1
while get_page(page):
    page += 1
```

Comment: That's amazing! However, there is a problem. This approach does not give me some information I need: 1) 5k,10k,...,40k splits, 2) Age-Group place, 3) Overall Gun place, 4) Team. Is there a way to get this information using your method?

Comment: You can try inspecting the AJAX request which is sent to the server on every "Show more" click to see which data is sent to the server. After that, try changing the post data dict we have in the line: 
request = requests.post(API_URL, {....})

Comment: Thank you! Now I'm trying to replicate the request that is sent when I click on "expand results". I hope it works :)